# Pre-Populated DB with support of creating entries by App Users as well

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

We are working on an app in which we are using a Data Base.
The DataBase will be containing pre-filled information which will be presented to user as and when it is required.

The application also has a provision to create multiple users account, login with them, switch accounts and create their profile and save their settings related data. Now as this information source is specific to user and is provided by the user, so it will only be available once the user provides it and since these are user preferences and account details so we require a way to save these details on device, and to do so again we choose Data Base. Also we are using the same DataBase with different tables to store both types of information, namely-

1) Pre-filled data contained in the DB and 
2) User created data stored in the DB,

The above two approaches work fine when these are used independently, in other words, at a time only one will work, reason being the DB File in which approach of point 1 works is saved in Applications Bundle and the 2nd type of DB File is saved in documents directory. The DataBase pointer can point to only one directory at a a time, thus only one approach amongst the above two will work.

What we are looking for is a way to use both the approaches, using a single DB.

Any solution related to supporting both type of data in one DB, in a single directory will be beneficial.

Thanks for reading the problem, and thanks in advance for your valuable time and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Each time your app starts, look for the database file in the Documents folder. If it doesn't exist, copy the original database file from the resource bundle to the Documents folder. From that point forward your open and use only the database file in the Documents folder. Then you can read and write any data you need.